# Chat invitations from outside domain

Tags: google-workspace, google-talk

I'm not the Google Apps Admin but he wants me to create a Gmail account and add it to chat so that everyone else in the domain can talk with this Gmail account.

The problem I'm having is I that most of the invites aren't showing.  I've sent an invite from `account@gmail.com` to `user1@domain.com`, `user2@domain.com`, `user3@domain.com`, etc. and only the accounts from the IT department have the invite show up from `account@gmail.com`.

Now I just want to know if there's a setting that blocks chat invites from outside the domain?

Because if there is, I think he probably enabled it since he restricts a lot of other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

check out the following steps

1. At Administration Console, go to **Orgs and Users > Orgs**, and then click the users organization
2. on organization management page ,click **sender's list** below the **inbound service section**
3. On the **Sender Lists** page, in the **Approved Senders field**, enter approved addresses or domains that apply for all users in this org. Separate multiple addresses with a comma.
4. Click Add.
5. Similarly, add senders whose messages you want to block for all users in the Blocked Senders field, and then click Add.